# работа с git в Eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse

Только начал изучать *Git*. Учусь работать через *git bash* , и через плагин в *Eclipse*.

В глобальном репозитории, коммиты делают два человека на одну ветку.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне с глобального репозиториия забрать последние изменения и слить с одной из веток на моем локальном репозитории, средставами плагина *Eclipse* и с помощью *git bash*?

Comment: В командной строке для второго случая, находясь в *mylocalbranch*: `git pull origin myremotebranch`.

Answer (score 2):

Работа с гитом в Eclipse ничем не отличается от работы с гитом вообще. Основные действия выведены на кнопки (наведите мышкой - увидите подсказки). Остальное зависит от вашей схемы работы с гитом, здесь нужно больше деталей.

> как мне с глобального репозиториия забрать последние изменения

Нажать на соответствующую кнопку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> слить с одной из веток на моем локальном репозитории

Нажать на соответствующую кнопку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зря, хороший ответ был. Иногда нужно объяснять вот так, очень подробно.

Comment: Ну и в нем есть предельно простая, но важная идея: «Работа с гитом в Eclipse ничем не отличается от работы с гитом вообще».

Comment: @NickVolynkin, OK, уговорили. Но я по-прежнему считаю, что ответ, дублирующий банальное руководство пользователя - да что там, действия любого, кто умеет возить мышкой - вреден. И по сути ничем не отличается от RTFM.